# Create RelNode of a select query with concat

Tags: apache-calcite

I went through the documentation of Apache Calcite. Is the `relNode` correct for the following query in BigQuery?

```
SELECT CONCAT('a or b',' ', '\n', first_name) 
FROM foo.schema.employee
WHERE first_name = 'name';
```

```
relNode = builder
          .scan("schema.employee")
          .filter(builder.call(SqlStdOperatorTable.EQUALS,
                         builder.field("first_name"), 
                         builder.literal("name"))
          .project(builder.call(SqlStdOperatorTable.CONCAT,
                           builder.literal("a or b"),
                           builder.literal(" "),
                           builder.literal("\\n"),
                           builder.field(first_name)))
          .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks correct at a glance. I would suggest you confirm by looking at the query results and also by converting your `RelNode` to SQL.